# How to convert a datetime string to UTC?

Tags: php, datetime

How can i convert a datetime string like this: `2012-09-03 22:00` US Estern to UTC timezone?

Comment: Even if you could mark comments as answer, the point still stands: it is expected that you show what you have tried. What you want to do is trivial using PHP's basic datetime functions and classes, but you seem to have found none of that all? Do you want the code to be written out for you?

Comment: [Take a leaf out of Jon Skeet's book](http://vimeo.com/7516539) and ask yourself - do you *actually* need this? Is it inside your little box, or are you adding a very difficult to create and unmanageable feature that nobody will ever use? How will *you* handle the Argentine government deciding 11 days in advance not to observe daylight savings?

Comment: This is not a help site, it's a Q&A site. Ask a good question and you will get dito answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object and its related functions in the documentation.

If your input date is already in a string format, [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will help you create an epoch-type integer date the object can work with. After that, it's just [`getTimezone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php) and [`setTimezone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your timestamps from DB to epoch time with `strtotime` and wrap them in a special CSS class :

```
<span class="timestamp"><?php echo strtotime('2012-09-03 22:00'); ?></span>
```

And then with a bit of a Javascript (jQuery example), dynamically transform the unix epoch into a locale datetime :

```
    $('.timestamp').each(function(){
        var seconds = $(this).html();
        var d = new Date(1000 * parseInt(seconds));
        var t = (d.getMonth()<9 ? '0':'') + parseInt(d.getMonth()+1) + '/';
        t+= (d.getDate()<10 ? '0' : '') + parseInt(d.getDate()) + '/';  
        t+= parseInt((d.getYear()<1000 ? d.getYear()+1900 : d.getYear())) + ' ';
        t+= (d.getHours()<10 ? '0' : '') + d.getHours() + ':' + (d.getMinutes()<10 ? '0' : '') + d.getMinutes();            
        $(this).html(t);
    });
```

This will output dates in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii`, relative to browser timezone.