# Is it possible to get the timezone from your visitor with php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

Or can this only be done with javascript (client-side)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344221/12910765
this may help in showing php now time in visitor's time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The most obvious way is to use Javascript since it lives in the client world.  The other way is to have users specify their time zone when they register for your site and then you can do some back end manipulations based on GMT to get the actual time they visited.  This of course has the flaw that the user can put in the wrong time zone.

Comment: "the user can put in the wrong time zone" Sure, but why should he/she do so? To calculate any times in their mind?

Comment: @feeela if there is a default choice of say GMT -4 there is a high probability that most users will have GMT -4 as their time zone.

Comment: That is possible and not your problem but the users one. The default itself should be UTC.

Comment: thank you all for your replies. about the registration thing... people are too lazy to register if they don't have to. no problem i will do it in javascript. i just wanted to make sure that it's impossible to do it in php.

Comment: @tastro : all 3 questions that you asked in the last 2 hours are very connected, and i already gave you a solution on how to do this with Javascript here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844617/store-date-in-utc-with-php Thank you for considering the effort people make for you and at least read their answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using PHP alone. But you could set a GET parameter via JS to the users current timestamp and compare the difference to a timestamp generated on the server. That way you compute the timezone difference between your server and your client.

Comment: It is possible using PHP. GeoIP!

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions

1. You can try to use javascript - and send with ajax to your script, but it's not 100% accurate.
2. You can use GeoIP and then match that to see his timezone.

Comment: Your second option is even less accurate than using JS, especially if you are using some free (without charge) database.

Comment: I didn't said it is free or payed ... but is more accurate that Javascript - because it's not browser/PC dependent.

Comment: Have your ever worked with GeoIP? The results are not accurate at all. Most IP's I tried to resolve were off a few hundred kilometers, but some were as far off that they reside in a different timezone. Also GeoIP data needs to get updated every few months. Nothing I would rely on.

Comment: There are always problems that have answers. He can use both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this can only be done in Javascript. A `timezone` is not included in the header. Therefore it must be combined with a language like `PHP`. Here are some solutions :

[How do I get a visitor's time zone in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718935/how-do-i-get-a-visitors-time-zone-in-php)

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/